# How can I set timeout in MvvmCross.Plugins.Network.Rest?

Tags: rest, xamarin, plugins, timeout, mvvmcross

This is the code in my UserService:

```
var request = new MvxRestRequest("http://localhost:8080/user/auth");

var client = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxRestClient>();

MvxStreamRestResponse response = await client.MakeStreamRequestAsync(request);

messageService.showMessage(response.StatusCode.ToString()); //Never reached when my server is down
```

When my REST is down, I never get the control again. How can I set a Timeout or another approach in this case?

Comment: Does the `MakeStreamRequestAsync` have an overload that takes a `CancellationToken`?

Answer (score 3):

`MakeStreamRequestAsync` has an [overload which takes a `CancellationToken`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross-Plugins/Network/MvvmCross.Plugins.Network/Rest/IMvxRestClient.cs#L24):

```
Task<MvxStreamRestResponse> MakeStreamRequestAsync(MvxRestRequest restRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

You could use it with a `CancellationTokenSource` and have that decide when to time out the request:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var response = await client.MakeStreamRequestAsync(request, cts.Token);
```

Comment: Perfect solution!